# Javascript Regex problems around braces

Tags: javascript, regex

The following program I wrote

```js
var textRegEx = /.{1,3}/g;
var text = "AUZ01A1";
var woohooMatch = text.match(textRegEx);
var finalResult = woohooMatch.join(' - ')

console.log(finalResult);
```

gives the output as:

```
Output:

AUZ - 01A - 1
```

I want the output to be `AUZ - 01 - A1`. How do I alter textRegEx to achieve this? I tried (2, 3} and some other things, but it doesn't work. I am new to both javascript and regex. Can you please help?

Comment: Could you describe why do you believe it should be splited this way?

Comment: The bigger web application that this code snippet will be a part of, has this UI/display requirement. It has to look that way to the user.

Comment: I mean what kind of rule should be used to split? Based on content of string? Based on length only?

Comment: Yes, you are right, just length. The seven alphanumeric characters have to be split 3-2-2

Comment: And input is always 7 symbols in length?

Comment: Input can be 6, 7 and 8 characters. 6 should be split in groups of 2(2-2-2). 7 should be grouped as (3-2-2) and 8 characters as (7-1). I was able to handle the 6 and 8. But did not know how to get the 7-char one right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use groups `()` to match pattern of 3,2,2 characters:

```js
var text = "AUZ01A1";
var textRegEx = /(.{3})(.{2})(.{2})/;
var woohooMatch = text.match(textRegEx);
var [ , ...matches] = woohooMatch;
var finalResult = matches.join(' - ');


console.log(finalResult);
```

Answer (score 1):

Separate cases of `6`/`7`, `8` and other by a simple `switch` statement:

```js
function format(string) {
  switch (string.length) {
    case 6:
    case 7:
      return string.match(
        /^(.{2,3})(.{2})(.{2})$/
      ).slice(1).join(' - ');
    break;
    case 8:
      return string.match(
        /^(.{7})(.)$/
      ).slice(1).join(' - ');
    default:
      return string;
  }
}
```

Or, if you prefer a tricky regex in a terse function:

```js
function format(string) {
  const match = string.match(/^(?=.{6,8}$)(?:.{7}|.{2,3})(?=(.{1}$|.{2})(.{2})?$)/);
  return match ? (match[2] ? match : match.slice(0, -1)).join(' - ') : string;
}
```

Explanation for the regex, the rest is left as an exercise for the reader:

```
^                # Match at the beginning of string
(?=.{6,8}$)      # a string of 6, 7 or 8 characters long, which consists of
(?:.{7}|.{2,3})  # a capturing group of either 7 or 2 to 3 characters
(?=              # followed by
  (.(?:.|$))     # a second capturing group of a character followed by another or the end of string
  (.{2})?        # and an optional capturing group of two characters.
  $              # right before the end of string.
)                #
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/dLrpBq/2).

Try it:

```js
function format1(string) {
  switch (string.length) {
    case 6:
    case 7:
      return string.match(
        /^(.{2,3})(.{2})(.{2})$/
      ).slice(1).join(' - ');
    break;
    case 8:
      return string.match(
        /^(.{7})(.)$/
      ).slice(1).join(' - ');
    default:
      return string;
  }
}

function format2(string) {
  const match = string.match(/^(?=.{6,8}$)(?:.{7}|.{2,3})(?=(.{1}$|.{2})(.{2})?$)/);
  return match ? (match[2] ? match : match.slice(0, -1)).join(' - ') : string;
}

// Test cases
const strings = [...'1234567890'].map(
  (_, i, a) => a.slice(0, i + 1).join('')
);

console.log(strings.map(format1));
console.log(strings.map(format2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your format, you can use an alternation with capture groups.

Then in the result, remove the full match and join the capture groups with `-`

Note that a `.` matches any character. If you only want to match uppercase chars or digits, you can use a character class `[A-Z\d]`

```
^(?:(.{2,3})(..)(..)|(.)(.{7}))$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `(.{2,3})(..)(..)` 3 capture groups, where the first group has 2 or 3 chars
  - `|` Or
  - `(.)(.{7})` 2 capture groups, where the first has a single char and the second group 7 chars
- `)` Close the non capture groups
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pmdeu0/1)

```js
const regex = /^(?:(.{2,3})(..)(..)|(.)(.{7}))$/gm;
const s = `AUZ01A
AUZ01A1
AUZ01A11`;

for (const match of s.matchAll(regex)) {
  const result = match.slice(1)
    .filter(Boolean)
    .join(' - ');
  console.log(result);
}
```